# Join/Merge on date range from two tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

Good day. I have two tables, tableA and tableB. I thought I had it but apparently I am doing something wrong on my join.

TableA has a few dates with datapoints. 
TableB has just a range of dates.

I want to merge or join both tables based on tableA's dates being between tableB' dates. How do I join tables based on each others tables dates? An help is most appreciated. Thanks.

Query

```
  SELECT o.processval, 
           u.datepar 
    FROM   @tblA o 
           LEFT JOIN @tblB u 
                  ON u.datepar >= o.dateentered 
                     AND u.datepar <= o.dateentered
```

tblA Data

```
   processval   dateentered
0   2018-07-26 12:47:18.480
14.7514 2018-07-26 12:47:18.480
27.2616 2018-07-26 12:47:18.480
26.7243 2018-07-26 12:47:18.480
60.8281 2018-07-26 12:47:18.480
63.4687 2018-07-26 12:47:18.480
60.9732 2018-07-26 12:47:18.480
68.0573 2018-07-26 12:47:18.480
0   2018-07-26 12:47:48.213
14.7555 2018-07-26 12:47:48.213
27.2591 2018-07-26 12:47:48.213
26.7345 2018-07-26 12:47:48.213
60.8154 2018-07-26 12:47:48.213
63.4356 2018-07-26 12:47:48.213
60.9401 2018-07-26 12:47:48.213
68.1057 2018-07-26 12:47:48.213
0   2018-07-26 12:47:48.483
14.7555 2018-07-26 12:47:48.483
27.2591 2018-07-26 12:47:48.483
26.7345 2018-07-26 12:47:48.483
60.8154 2018-07-26 12:47:48.483
63.4356 2018-07-26 12:47:48.483
60.9401 2018-07-26 12:47:48.483
68.1057 2018-07-26 12:47:48.483
0   2018-07-26 12:48:18.483
21.1506 2018-07-26 12:48:18.483
27.1649 2018-07-26 12:48:18.483
27.0706 2018-07-26 12:48:18.483
61.3094 2018-07-26 12:48:18.483
64.7775 2018-07-26 12:48:18.483
61.8161 2018-07-26 12:48:18.483
70.0078 2018-07-26 12:48:18.483
0   2018-07-26 12:48:48.487
22.8971 2018-07-26 12:48:48.487
27.0859 2018-07-26 12:48:48.487
26.9688 2018-07-26 12:48:48.487
70.9347 2018-07-26 12:48:48.487
68.5385 2018-07-26 12:48:48.487
67.7925 2018-07-26 12:48:48.487
72.6892 2018-07-26 12:48:48.487
0   2018-07-26 12:49:18.487
23.5001 2018-07-26 12:49:18.487
30.5184 2018-07-26 12:49:18.487
26.9102 2018-07-26 12:49:18.487
71.5178 2018-07-26 12:49:18.487
69.906  2018-07-26 12:49:18.487
68.867  2018-07-26 12:49:18.487
84.3287 2018-07-26 12:49:18.487
0   2018-07-26 12:49:48.490
23.9836 2018-07-26 12:49:48.490
36.8819 2018-07-26 12:49:48.490
26.844  2018-07-26 12:49:48.490
73.7739 2018-07-26 12:49:48.490
71.9634 2018-07-26 12:49:48.490
71.0493 2018-07-26 12:49:48.490
93.7401 2018-07-26 12:49:48.490
0   2018-07-26 12:50:18.490
24.6327 2018-07-26 12:50:18.490
44.1773 2018-07-26 12:50:18.490
26.8567 2018-07-26 12:50:18.490
76.1497 2018-07-26 12:50:18.490
74.3621 2018-07-26 12:50:18.490
73.4811 2018-07-26 12:50:18.490
99.4975 2018-07-26 12:50:18.490
```

tblB DATA

```
datePar
2018-07-26 12:47:18.060
2018-07-26 12:48:18.060
2018-07-26 12:49:18.060
2018-07-26 12:50:18.060
2018-07-26 12:51:18.060
```

Desired Results

```
processval  dateentered
0   12:48:18:060 
14.7514 12:48:18:060
27.2616 12:48:18:060
26.7243 12:48:18:060
60.8281 12:48:18:060
63.4687 12:48:18:060
60.9732 12:48:18:060
68.0573 12:48:18:060
0   12:48:18:060
14.7555 12:48:18:060
27.2591 12:48:18:060
26.7345 12:48:18:060
60.8154 12:48:18:060
63.4356 12:48:18:060
60.9401 12:48:18:060
68.1057 12:48:18:060
0   12:48:18:060
14.7555 12:48:18:060
27.2591 12:48:18:060
26.7345 12:48:18:060
60.8154 12:48:18:060
63.4356 12:48:18:060
60.9401 12:48:18:060
68.1057 12:48:18:060
0   12:49:18:060
21.1506 12:49:18:060
27.1649 12:49:18:060
27.0706 12:49:18:060
61.3094 12:49:18:060
64.7775 12:49:18:060
61.8161 12:49:18:060
70.0078 12:49:18:060
0   12:49:18:060
22.8971 12:49:18:060
27.0859 12:49:18:060
26.9688 12:49:18:060
70.9347 12:49:18:060
68.5385 12:49:18:060
67.7925 12:49:18:060
72.6892 12:49:18:060
0   12:50:18:060
23.5001 12:50:18:060
30.5184 12:50:18:060
26.9102 12:50:18:060
71.5178 12:50:18:060
69.906  12:50:18:060
68.867  12:50:18:060
84.3287 12:50:18:060
0   12:50:18:060
23.9836 12:50:18:060
36.8819 12:50:18:060
26.844  12:50:18:060
73.7739 12:50:18:060
71.9634 12:50:18:060
71.0493 12:50:18:060
93.7401 12:50:18:060
0   12:51:18:060
24.6327 12:51:18:060
44.1773 12:51:18:060
26.8567 12:51:18:060
76.1497 12:51:18:060
74.3621 12:51:18:060
73.4811 12:51:18:060
99.4975 12:51:18:060
```

The table A is using the values that are within the data range of tableB. Any help is most appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use `LEAD` function get the next DateTime from `tblB`, then `join` with `tblA` by the during DateTime.

```
SELECT processval,nextDt FROM tblA a 
inner join (
    select *,lead(datePar,1,datePar)  over(order by datePar) nextDt
    from tblB
) b on a.dateentered between b.datePar and b.nextDt
```

[sqlfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=5ff654ee7d745f3d3acea2aae0b831b2)

Comment: @arios you can try this.

Answer (score 0):

I needed a second datetime column for tblB for the last operand `'<='`. I could  have went recursive; but the column already existed so I just needed to call it so I could compare against it.